# Generic scala function whose input is a function of variable arity

Tags: scala, generics

I want to define a function `f` that takes another function `g`. We require `g` to take take `n` Doubles (for some fixed `n`) and return a Double. The function call `f(g)` should return the specific value of `n`.

For example, `f(Math.max) = 2` since Math.sin has type `(Double, Double) => Double`, and `f(Math.sin) = 1` since Math.sin has type `Double => Double`.

How can I define `f` using Scala generics?

I've tried several forms without success. For example:

```
def f[A <: Product](g: Product => Double) = {...}
```

This doesn't work since we cannot extract the value of `n` at compile time, and cannot constrain the `A` to contain only `Double` values.

Comment: You say that `g` takes an n-tuple, but your example `Math.max` is an n-ary function, not a `Function1` that takes a tuple. You should clarify that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a pattern called [Magnet Pattern](http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/), created by the [Spray](http://spray.io/) team. It does exectly what you want

Answer (score 6):

This was a good excuse for me to look into [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), something I always wanted to do at some point :)

```
$ git clone git@github.com:milessabin/shapeless.git
...
$ cd shapeless
```

(1)

Shapeless provides some abstractions over arity, and especially the representation as heterogeneous list (`HList`). A function of arbitrary arity can be seen as `FnHList` (a function that takes an `HList` as argument).

```
$ sbt shapeless-core/console
scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> def isFunction[A](fun: A)(implicit fnh: FnHLister[A]) {}
isFunction: [A](fun: A)(implicit fnh: shapeless.FnHLister[A])Unit

scala> isFunction(math.sqrt _)

scala> isFunction(math.random _)
```

(2)

Now let's require that the function returns a `Double`:

```
scala> def isFunReturningDouble[A](fun: A)(implicit fnh: FnHLister[A] { type Result = Double }) {}
isFunReturningDouble: [A](fun: A)(implicit fnh: shapeless.FnHLister[A]{type Result = Double})Unit

scala> isFunReturningDouble(math.sqrt _)

scala> isFunReturningDouble(math.signum _)
<console>:12: error: could not find implicit value for parameter fnh: shapeless.FnHLister[Int => Int]{type Result = Double}
              isFunReturningDouble(math.signum _)
                                  ^
```

(3)

The `LUBConstraint` type class can witness the upper bound of the argument list:

```
scala> def isValidFun[A, B <: HList](fun: A)(implicit fnh: FnHLister[A] { type Result = Double; type Args = B }, lub: LUBConstraint[B, Double]) {}
isValidFun: [A, B <: shapeless.HList](fun: A)(implicit fnh: shapeless.FnHLister[A]{type Result = Double; type Args = B}, implicit lub: shapeless.LUBConstraint[B,Double])Unit

scala> isValidFun(math.random _)

scala> isValidFun((i: Int) => i.toDouble)
<console>:12: error: could not find implicit value for parameter lub: shapeless.LUBConstraint[B,Double]
              isValidFun((i: Int) => i.toDouble)
                        ^
```

(4)

Now we still need to extract the arity somehow. On the type level this would be `Length` which is provided for `HList`. To get a runtime value, another type class `ToInt` is needed.

**Here is the final function:**

```
import shapeless._

def doubleFunArity[A, B <: HList, C <: Nat](fun: A)(implicit
  fnh: FnHLister[A] { type Result = Double; type Args = B }, 
  lub: LUBConstraint[B, Double],
  len: Length[B] { type Out = C },
  res: ToInt[C]
): Int = res()
```

Test:

```
scala> doubleFunArity(math.sqrt _)
res15: Int = 1

scala> doubleFunArity(math.random _)
res16: Int = 0

scala> val g: (Double, Double) => Double = math.max _
g: (Double, Double) => Double = <function2>

scala> doubleFunArity(g)
res17: Int = 2
```

Note that unfortunately many `math` operations are overloaded, and without strong type constraint, Scala will not give you the `Double` version automatically, but will use the `Int` version for some reason:

```
scala> math.max _
res18: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

So I need the indirection `math.max _: ((Double, Double) => Double)` to make this work.

---

Not saying that this is the best way to do it in your concrete case, but I think it was a fun exploration.

Comment: P.S. `math.max(_: Double, _: Double)` will also do

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest solution is to use overloading as

```
def f(g: () => Double) = 0;
def f(g: (Double) => Double) = 1;
def f(g: (Double, Double) => Double) = 2;
def f(g: (Double, Double, Double) => Double) = 2;
// ...

println(f(Math.pow _));
println(f(Math.sin _));
```

(You can't check function argument/return types at run time due to type erasure, so I believe you can't create a fully generic function that would satisfy your requirements.)